# What are the other Animal Guides?

Tags: avatar

When Aang was in the Spirit World during the Winter Solstice he refereed to Roku's Dragon as Roku's Animal Guide like how Appa is to him.

I am wondering what are the Animal Guides for the other Avatars? do each Elemental Tribe have a single animal (ie. Air Avatars have Sky Bisons, Fire Avatars have Dragons) do does each Avatar have their own one regardless of elemental origin?

Comment: Unagi (Water) & Blind Mole (Earth)

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible to say whether the other avatars had Animal Guides. The only ones we see are Korra's, Aang's, and Roku's. Kyoshi, Kuruk, Yangchen, and Wan were never seen with one. Of those, Wan was the only one we really got a lot of backstory for and he was never seen with an animal guide, though it seemed Ravaa may have been the equivalent for him.

While the earth kingdom avatars are never seen with an animal, ***if*** the other three avatar animal guides we've seen are indicative of their respective elements' animal guides then it would be:

- Dragons for Fire Avatars
- Air Bison for Air Avatars
- Polar Bear Dogs for Water Avatars.

There isn't much information that I could find on this subject, so this is the best answer I was able to come up with

Comment: Just to add some thought to your last part, I would think it can be any animal they make a strong bond with. If it were limited to just those listed, Fire Avatars are a bit screwed. I wouldn't think the Fire Nation would kill off so many dragons if it would highly benefit their eventual future Avatar.

Answer (score 0):

Wan and Yangchen did have animal guides, wans was that leopard with antlers, in not sure exactly what it is, but it was around that, and he traveled with it, the animal guide was a gift for wan making a bond with the spirits, so that’s why the avatar gets animal guides in general, and yangchen got 2 flying leagues, pik and pak I think their names were, it’s been a while okay??  Kuruk and Kyoshi kept theirs a secret, even from their closest friends, and avatar setzo probably did the same because his wasn’t mentioned ‍♀️

Answer (score 0):

Didn’t Kyoshi have the bison too from the book?

The previous avatar’s friend’s bison that stuck around after the Airbender died to help Kyoshi

His name was pongpong

Comment: I believe you actually mean [Pengpeng](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Pengpeng)?